# Unable to configure Firebase app for Unity IOS

Tags: ios, windows, firebase, unity-game-engine

I have been looking around constantly and can't find any solution to this. I built my IOS project with Unity and it compiled fine. I'm just getting run time errors that I can't seem to solve at all.

When I run with Unity test mode it runs fine, (no errors and config loads).

When I compile and run on my IOS device, I get a bunch of runtime errors, and I can't even get past the loading screen because Firebase can't load.

The top is just all dupe error (There are more than two but I included just examples) and at the bottom is the "Unable to configure Firebase app" error.

BTW: I build my project on Windows using IOS Project Builder, so I added & linked the frameworks manually. I'm not able to add the FirebaseApp.configure b/c I'm not on swift.

```
Mon 11 23:48:33.974 RemoteConsole <stderr>: objc[11431]: Class FIRAnalyticsConnector is implemented in both /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/0080BEB1-979B-48A5-AFE9-F25C7FD60E6D/cashcrates.app/cashcrates (0x10240a3b8) and /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/0080BEB1-979B-48A5-AFE9-F25C7FD60E6D/cashcrates.app/Frameworks/UnityFramework.framework/UnityFramework (0x10624fd10). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Mon 11 23:48:33.974 RemoteConsole <stderr>: objc[11431]: Class FIRConnectorUtils is implemented in both /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/0080BEB1-979B-48A5-AFE9-F25C7FD60E6D/cashcrates.app/cashcrates (0x10240a408) and /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/0080BEB1-979B-48A5-AFE9-F25C7FD60E6D/cashcrates.app/Frameworks/UnityFramework.framework/UnityFramework (0x10624fd60). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.


Mon 11 23:48:34.115 RemoteConsole <stderr>: 2020-05-11 23:48:34.333 cashcrates[11431:2281069] Built from '2019.3/staging' branch, Version '2019.3.12f1 (84b23722532d)', Build type 'Release', Scripting Backend 'il2cpp'
Mon 11 23:48:34.193 RemoteConsole <stderr>: 2020-05-11 23:48:34.411 cashcrates[11431:2281069] GfxDevice: creating device client; threaded=1
Mon 11 23:48:34.193 RemoteConsole <stdout>: CrashReporter: initialized
Mon 11 23:48:34.193 RemoteConsole <stdout>: -> applicationDidFinishLaunching()
Mon 11 23:48:34.193 RemoteConsole <stdout>: -> applicationDidBecomeActive()
Mon 11 23:48:34.193 RemoteConsole <stdout>: GfxDevice: creating device client; threaded=1
Mon 11 23:48:34.236 RemoteConsole <stderr>: 2020-05-11 23:48:34.412 cashcrates[11431:2281069] Initializing Metal device caps: Apple A12 GPU
Mon 11 23:48:34.236 RemoteConsole <stderr>: 2020-05-11 23:48:34.413 cashcrates[11431:2281069] Initialize engine version: 2019.3.12f1 (84b23722532d)
Mon 11 23:48:34.236 RemoteConsole <stdout>: Initializing Metal device caps: Apple A12 GPU
Mon 11 23:48:34.236 RemoteConsole <stdout>: Initialize engine version: 2019.3.12f1 (84b23722532d)
Mon 11 23:48:34.334 RemoteConsole <stdout>: CrashReporter: No pending report exists at /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/5CC73465-87AF-475C-BE86-AE7993321E3B/Library/Caches/CrashReports/crash-pending.plcrash
Mon 11 23:48:34.334 RemoteConsole <stderr>: 2020-05-11 23:48:34.552 cashcrates[11431:2281069] CrashReporter: No pending report exists at /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/5CC73465-87AF-475C-BE86-AE7993321E3B/Library/Caches/CrashReports/crash-pending.plcrash
Mon 11 23:48:34.387 RemoteConsole <stderr>: 2020-05-11 23:48:34.576 cashcrates[11431:2281069] Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <SplashScreenController: 0x135d62c30>.
Mon 11 23:48:36.368 RemoteConsole <stdout>: UnloadTime: 2.304417 ms
Mon 11 23:48:36.368 RemoteConsole <stderr>: 2020-05-11 23:48:36.579 cashcrates[11431:2281069] UnloadTime: 2.304417 ms
Mon 11 23:48:36.413 RemoteConsole <stdout>: Fetching data...
Mon 11 23:48:36.413 RemoteConsole <stdout>: Config:FetchDataAsync()
Mon 11 23:48:36.413 RemoteConsole <stdout>: Config:Start()
Mon 11 23:48:36.413 RemoteConsole <stdout>: 
Mon 11 23:48:36.413 RemoteConsole <stdout>: (Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35)
Mon 11 23:48:36.413 RemoteConsole <stdout>: 
Mon 11 23:48:36.413 RemoteConsole <stderr>: 2020-05-11 23:48:36.627 cashcrates[11431:2281069] Fetching data...
Mon 11 23:48:36.413 RemoteConsole <stderr>: Config:FetchDataAsync()
Mon 11 23:48:36.413 RemoteConsole <stderr>: Config:Start()
Mon 11 23:48:36.413 RemoteConsole <stderr>: 
Mon 11 23:48:36.413 RemoteConsole <stderr>: (Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35)
Mon 11 23:48:36.413 RemoteConsole <stderr>: 
Mon 11 23:48:36.429 RemoteConsole <stderr>: 2020-05-11 23:48:36.641 cashcrates[11431:2281069] ERROR: Unable to configure Firebase app (The default FirebaseApp instance must be configured before the defaultFirebaseApp instance can be initialized. One way to ensure that is to call `[FIRApp configure];` (`FirebaseApp.configure()` in Swift) in the App Delegate's `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` (`application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` in Swift).)
Mon 11 23:48:36.429 RemoteConsole <stderr>: 2020-05-11 23:48:36.645 cashcrates[11431:2281069] Uploading Crash Report
Mon 11 23:48:36.429 RemoteConsole <stderr>: 2020-05-11 23:48:36.646 cashcrates[11431:2281069] InitializationException:  Firebase app creation failed.
Mon 11 23:48:36.429 RemoteConsole <stderr>:  at Firebase.FirebaseApp.CreateAndTrack (Firebase.FirebaseApp+CreateDelegate createDelegate, Firebase.FirebaseApp existingProxy) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
Mon 11 23:48:36.429 RemoteConsole <stderr>:   at Config.FetchDataAsync () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
Mon 11 23:48:36.429 RemoteConsole <stderr>:  at Config.Start () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
Mon 11 23:48:36.429 RemoteConsole <stderr>: 
Mon 11 23:48:36.429 RemoteConsole <stderr>: (Filename: currently not available on il2cpp Line: -1)
Mon 11 23:48:36.429 RemoteConsole <stderr>: 
Mon 11 23:48:36.429 RemoteConsole <stderr>: 2020-05-11 23:48:36.647 cashcrates[11431:2281069] Unable to configure Firebase app (The default FirebaseApp instance must be configured before the defaultFirebaseApp instance can be initialized. One way to ensure that is to call `[FIRApp configure];` (`FirebaseApp.configure()` in Swift) in the App Delegate's `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` (`application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` in Swift).)
Mon 11 23:48:36.429 RemoteConsole <stderr>: Firebase.AppUtil:PollCallbacks()
Mon 11 23:48:36.429 RemoteConsole <stderr>: Firebase.Platform.FirebaseHandler:Update()
Mon 11 23:48:36.429 RemoteConsole <stderr>: 
Mon 11 23:48:36.429 RemoteConsole <stderr>: (Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35)
Mon 11 23:48:36.429 RemoteConsole <stderr>: 
Mon 11 23:48:36.457 RemoteConsole <stdout>: Uploading Crash Report
Mon 11 23:48:36.457 RemoteConsole <stdout>: InitializationException: Firebase app creation failed.
Mon 11 23:48:36.457 RemoteConsole <stdout>:   at Firebase.FirebaseApp.CreateAndTrack (Firebase.FirebaseApp+CreateDelegate createDelegate, Firebase.FirebaseApp existingProxy) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
Mon 11 23:48:36.457 RemoteConsole <stdout>:  at Config.FetchDataAsync () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
Mon 11 23:48:36.457 RemoteConsole <stdout>:   at Config.Start () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
Mon 11 23:48:36.457 RemoteConsole <stdout>:  
Mon 11 23:48:36.457 RemoteConsole <stdout>: (Filename: currently not available on il2cpp Line: -1)
Mon 11 23:48:36.457 RemoteConsole <stdout>: 
Mon 11 23:48:36.457 RemoteConsole <stdout>: Unable to configure Firebase app (The default FirebaseApp instance must be configured before the defaultFirebaseApp instance can be initialized. One way to ensure that is to call `[FIRApp configure];` (`FirebaseApp.configure()` in Swift) in the App Delegate's `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` (`application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` in Swift).)
Mon 11 23:48:36.457 RemoteConsole <stdout>: Firebase.AppUtil:PollCallbacks()
Mon 11 23:48:36.457 RemoteConsole <stdout>: Firebase.Platform.FirebaseHandler:Update()
Mon 11 23:48:36.457 RemoteConsole <stdout>:  
Mon 11 23:48:36.457 RemoteConsole <stdout>: (Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35)
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm having the same exact problem. iOS Project Builder for Unity, Firebase, same 'Unable to configure' error, which happens before any of my scripts actually run in my test app. I even tried using the mechahamster demo app and get the same issue. REALLY hoping I don't have to develop on a Mac to use firebase, when literally everything else I code works through Windows.

Answer (score 0):

This gets a little tricky if you can't use the [External Dependency Manager for Unity (EDM4U)](https://github.com/googlesamples/unity-jar-resolver), but it looks like your issue may be that you're missing GoogleService-Info.plist. Typically this will be copied over automatically as part of EDM4U running, but since you're bypassing that you'll want to do it manually. The configure step should happen automatically as part of calling `FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance` (or initializing any other singleton that depends on it).

You can try placing the file under `Assets/StreamingAssets` to see if that just fixes it, otherwise you'll have to move it over as part of your manually hooking up your frameworks. See [this](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7015592) if you need to download it again.

If that doesn't fix it, make sure you've followed the [getting started guide for iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup) (which it sounds like you've done). Don't be afraid to use CocoaPods, [EDM4U literally does this](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-manage-your-native-ios-and-android-dependencies-in-unity-like-firebase-921659843aef).

Also, don't ignore the files the unity bundles place under `Assets/Plugins/iOS/Firebase` (ex: `Assets/plugins/iOS/Firebase/libFirebaseCppApp.a`). I know that often times version control systems exclude `.a` files in an attempt to avoid tracking build artifacts. These files roughly map to [the C++ SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cpp/setup?platform=android), which the Firebase Unity SDK uses to communicate with the underlying frameworks. The C# layer is mainly built using [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) to generate the proper bindings, with some additional work to make it more convenient to use in Unity.

And finally, although I don't think there's extensive testing with generating iOS projects from Windows, I can see there being some demand. It would be helpful to file a bug asking about that [here](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues), and outlining the workarounds you've had to enact so far. Also filing a [feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report/features) is a great way to drum up support as well (and that applies to anyone finding this answer, not just the OP - the more noise the better).

Let me know if that helps!

--Patrick

Comment: Thank you, I tried putting this in the Assets/StreamingAssets and no luck but it seems like Firebase isn't able to find the GoogleService-Info.plist and my certificate too so that may just be the reason why. Do you know where I can manually put these files as the Asset folder doesn't seem to be working once compiled. Where would IOS usually check for these files?

Comment: The official instruction is to move it to the root of your XCode project (drag and drop it into the side bar -- https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#add-config-file). I did some experimentation and found that it doesn't seem to matter where you put it, as long as XCode can see it in the project (https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-use-firebase-in-ios-games-written-in-c-fef1a6a9f87d)..

Comment: I have tried everywhere and I still can't get it to work. I have the .xcodeproj file so is there's anything I have to write in project.pbxproj ? That seems to be the only file in there. `Tue 12 23:56:09.778 RemoteConsole <stdout>: cash-crates-14c93236a173 was not found.  Also looked in /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/CEF94124-1463-4A60-9059-B24AE71FD4DC/cashcrates.app/Data/Editor Default Resources/cash-crates-14c93236a173`

Also can I call FirebaseApp.configure() in Unity at all?

Comment: Oh right! I keep forgetting that you don't have XCode installed (sorry!). You may use a postprocessbuild hook (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Callbacks.PostProcessBuildAttribute.html) to edit the generated XCode project. You'll want to create a new PBXProject (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/iOS.Xcode.PBXProject-ctor.html), load it from the path from the postprocessbuild callback (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/iOS.Xcode.PBXProject.GetPBXProjectPath.html and https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/iOS.Xcode.PBXProject.ReadFromFile.html)

Comment: Add the file (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/iOS.Xcode.PBXProject.AddFile.html) and write it back out (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/iOS.Xcode.PBXProject.WriteToFile.html).

Comment: Basically, you want the application XCode to know that your plist exists. Which is hard without EDM4U running and without XCode to edit the file directly. Quick aside: if you're not familiar with MacOS, even though xcodeproj is a folder on most operating systems, it's considered a "bundle" to MacOS and is treated as a single file. One of the things throwing me off was remembering that on most operating systems, opening this is opening a folder rather than launching XCode 

Comment: Unforunately it didn't work :(
        `Debug.Log(pathToBuiltProject);
        string projPath = PBXProject.GetPBXProjectPath(pathToBuiltProject);
        Debug.Log(projPath);
        PBXProject pbx = new PBXProject();
        pbx.ReadFromFile(projPath);
        string target = pbx.GetUnityMainTargetGuid();
        Debug.Log(target);
        pbx.AddFileToBuild(target, pbx.AddFile("GoogleService-Info.plist", "GoogleService-Info.plist"));
        pbx.WriteToFile(projPath);
        Debug.Log("plist added");`

This was my code, I might just have to find another way.

Comment: Just wanted to add my experience with this. As a test I DELETED the GoogleService-Info.plist file from the xcode project directory, and when the app started I got a completely different error, about not finding the file. So the error the OP got (which is the same I originally got) is WITH the GoogleService-Info.plist file being loaded properly. I'm also using iOS Project Builder and literally EVERY framework I use compiles and runs great under windows on my iOS device, EXCEPT firebase.